# how to set the environment variables in python flask and jinja2

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

```
i am unable to set the environment variables from jinja2

<body>
    <h1>hi {{session['user']}}<h1>
        {{session['user']='Mad'}}
</body>

<body>
   <h1>
     hi {{session['user']}}
   <h1>
    {{session['user']='Mad'}}
</body>
```

I have already declared session['user'] in python code in flask but i am unable to set it in jinja2 that is the with the following html code

Comment: These kind of blackbox questions are likely to get downvoted.
please edit the question and include the error you get.

Comment: `jinja2` is for generating HTML which it will send to client, not for setting values in variables. You have code in `flask` for this.

Comment: why you try to assign value to variable ? What you try to get ?

Comment: You need to pass context while using flask render_template method, it takes the following arguments -> template_name_or_list, **context

Answer (score 2):

As described above, you need to define your variables within your backend and pass them to your template. For example:

**run.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'your-secret-key'

@app.route("/<user>")
def user_page(user):
   session['user'] = user
   return render_template("user_page.html", user=session['user'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

**user_page.html**

```
<body>
<h1>hi {{ user }}<h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this doesn't make sense. Jinja2 is an HTML templating system, used server-side to render a page; it is not meant to update global variable. The logic should be implemented in your python code, *before* calling the template. The repsonsibility is thus:

1. **python method**: does server-side logic and prepare the variables needed by Jinja2 to render the response page;
2. **jinja2 template**: simply render the page using the variables prepared in 1.

Hence, editing session content should never appear in Jinja2 (it wouldn't make any sense anyway), so move your line to the python code. If you need two different names, simply save the old session value to a new variable that you pass to jinja2 alongside the updated session.